# Mockery "with" method not showing why fails

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I'm using `with` method on a mock in order to assert that the method is called with an object as an argument

```
        Mockery::mock(PaymentRepository::class)
             ->shouldReceive('removeTripPayments')
             ->with($trip)
             ->mock();
```

Which fails, I still don't know why, but I'm mostly concerned about if this is the correct way to check it and if it is possible to show **how** the expected argument is different from the given one.

```
1) PaymentServiceTest::test_removing_payments
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_PaymentRepository::removeTripPayments(object(Trip)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Objects: ( array (
  'MyNamespace\Trip' =>
  array (
    'class' => 'MyNamespace\\Trip',
    'properties' =>
    array (
    ),
  ),
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing an object to the method as an argument, Which in this case you are passing object(Trip), Then PHPUnit getting crazy. I have always had this problem and you have two solutions for it, the first one using Mockery::on();

```
->with(Mockery::on(function($Param){
    $this->assertEqual(get_class($Param), get_class(Trip));
    return true;
}))
```

As you can see PHPUnit can't compare the two objects completely, so you need to compare part of the objects, which in this case I have used get_clas to check the name of the classes. And the second solution could be using

```
->andReturnUsing(function($param){
   $this->assertEqual(get_class($Param), get_class(Trip));
   return true; // Expected response
});
```

Maybe this can be helpful to you.

Comment: thanks mohammad, I do the same, using clousures to compare the fields specifically. There should be a way to compare them directly, sometimes I can get it done but when they are different is also hard to know which field is different